# Controlling python outputs to console

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I'm building a Movie recommendation using Hadoop/MapReduce.
Now I'm using only python to implement the MapReduce process.

So what I'm basically doing is running each mapper and reducer separately and using the console outputs from the mapper to the reducer.

The issue I'm having is that python outputs values as strings in the terminal, so if I'm working with numbers the numbers are printed as strings, which makes it difficult to simplify the process as the conversion of it adds more load on the server.

So how do I resolve this issue, I'm looking to implement it using pure python and no 3rd-party libs.

```
import sys

def mapper():
    '''
        From Mapper1 : we need only UserID , (MovieID , rating)
        as output.
    '''

    #* First mapper

    # Read input line
    for line in sys.stdin:
        # Strip whitespace and delimiter - ','
        print line
        data = line.strip().split(',')

        if len(data) == 4:
            # Using array to print out values
            # Direct printing , makes python interpret
            # values with comma in between as tuples
            # tempout = []
            userid , movieid , rating , timestamp = data
            # tempout.append(userid)
            # tempout.append((movieid , float(rating)))
            # print tempout

            #
            print "{0},({1},{2})".format(userid , movieid , rating)
```

Here's the reducer print statement:

```
def reducer():

    oldKey = None
    rating_arr = []

    for line in sys.stdin:
        # So we'll recieve user, (movie,rating)
        # We need to group the tuples for unique users
        # we'll append the tuples to an array
        # Given that we have two data points , we'll split the
        # data at only first occurance of ','
        # This splits the string only at first comma

        data = line.strip().split(',',1)
        # print len(data) , data
        # check for 2 data values
        if len(data) != 2:
            continue

        x , y = data

        if oldKey and oldKey != x:

            print "{0},{1}".format(oldKey , rating_arr)
            oldKey = x
            rating_arr = []
        oldKey = x
        rating_arr.append(y)
        # print rating_arr
    if oldKey != None:
        print "{0},{1}".format(oldKey , rating_arr)
```

`

Input is:

`671,(4973,4.5)\n671,(4993,5.0)\n670,(4995,4.0)`

The output is :

```
671,['(4973,4.5)', '(4993,5.0)']
670,['(4995,4.0)']
```

I need the the tuples as it is, no strings.

Comment: Python won't automatically convert tuples inside a list to strings, it seems your issue is upstream.

Comment: There is a lot of missing code here. Without it, we wont be much use.

Comment: Please check the updated code

Comment: Please show the output you want

Comment: @cricket_007 the values of the tuples are converted into string. , I need integer values

Comment: Your tuples are floats and integers. Please edit the question with the mapper and the final output you want

Comment: @cricket_007 the values printed from reducer is actually a string and not a tuple or list.
https://github.com/PadamSethia/hadoopwithpy/tree/master/Recommender/Movie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that data is a string, that you then split and assign `y` to it, it is *still a string*.

If you want the raw values of the tuple, as numbers, you need to parse them.

`ast.literal_eval` can help.

For example,

```
In [1]: line = """671,(4973,4.5)"""

In [2]:  data = line.strip().split(',',1)

In [3]: data
Out[3]: ['671', '(4973,4.5)']

In [4]: x , y = data

In [5]: type(y)
Out[5]: str

In [6]: import ast

In [7]: y = ast.literal_eval(y)

In [8]: y
Out[8]: (4973, 4.5)

In [9]: type(y)
Out[9]: tuple

In [10]: type(y[0])
Out[10]: int
```

Now, if you would like to switch to PySpark, you would have more control over the variable/object types rather than all strings with Hadoop Streaming

Comment: Sorry , but it doesn't seem to work , it gives Malformed string error.
the brackets seems to pose an issue.
Converting it to str and then using literal_eval still interprets the values inside the list as string , see the apostrophie.
Anything else that I should try ?
Is there any way to directly pass data between different mappers and reducer?

Comment: Obviously `print "%d"%rating_arr` doesn't work because an array is not a **d**ecimal number. You would  need to `print rating_arr` directly

Comment: However, your reducer should have consistent output. So you can use `print "{0},{1}".format(oldKey , rating_arr)` again, depending on what you need to do

Comment: yep , printing directly converts it to str ,  thats the proplem . Try runnin the reducer code here , and see the output.
https://github.com/PadamSethia/hadoopwithpy/blob/master/Recommender/Movie/reducer.py

Comment: I'm not able to run your code, I'm just explaining your error, which is unrelated to the provided answer using `ast`, but rather your other print statement

Comment: Okay, well now the indentation looks off, so what's the actual error? Add the traceback to the question

Comment: there's no error.What I want is to get the values inside the tuples as integers and not as str when it gets printed to the console.

Comment: It's always going to be a string when printed or parsed without casting or evaluating. Your link above is not using `ast`, so I don't understand your issue

Comment: Refering to the last print statement , how would you print it if you wanted the same output.
Also using ast gives malformed string as it also considers the brackets`[` which is not a string.

Comment: Got it , thanks ! 
I used ast on the values when appending to the list.

Comment: AST parses brackets just fine. And it only parses into correct python data structures. It's not responsible for formatting your output